# Make shared library (SDK) installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, reference, com

When importing dlls in Visual Studio (VS2017) I have to choose the path where the dll file is. If I move the dlls file later, or I share the project, reference will be broken.

I can see there is a COM option where you can see system DLLs plus some libraries from installed software.

How can I create a set of dll files (SDK) so I can see them there?

At this moment, I'm creating a lib folder in the solution directory where I put all my dlls, so I can import them easily and share the project including libraries.

The idea is that every developer must install an SDK with all these libraries in order to use them, and add them without having to copy files. It might make lib updates easier for us.

Also, when deploying the proyject solution will every user need the SDK installed? I guess I have to mark the library for local copy.

Comment: If you are using .NET core, you can create a self-contained deployment with all dependencies. For classic .NET you can create an installer package (wix, clickonce) to ship to the user

Comment: I'm using .net 4-4.5. Not core yet.